# PHPExcel: importing xls, date format to Y-m-d

Tags: excel, date-format

Following the examples provided in the documentation (in particular example 07reader.php) I have managed to extract all the data I needed from an excel file.

However the files I need to import have date values that need to be converted to `Y-m-d`, so I was wondering if PHPExcel can always output dates in a certain format.

Does anyone know hot to do it? I've looked in the [official forum](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions), but I haven't found any solution, and I didn't get how to do it looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPExcel will show date formats according to the defined format mask. There are a number of helper functions available that will allow you to convert an Excel timestamp value to a PHP/unix timestamp or to a PHP DateTime object: like `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP()` and `PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject()`